# Ajax file Upload multiple

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I am developing a website in Asp.net 4.0 .
 I have placed 5 Ajax FileUplload Control on a page.
But only 1st control's UploadComplete event is fired.
For rest 4 controls "Upload Completed" Event is **not** fired.
Please Help me.

Thanks In  Advance.

Comment: Personally I do prefer _one_ upload control that allows selecting multiple files at once.

Answer (score 0):

try Javascript or Jquery and check if you can find FileUpload Control IDs on Windows.Onload event ..or if you are finding this difficult then best you can deal with this is by using FireBug  in Firefox .. It is the best tool where you can easily check if your other 4 fileUpload controls are properly get rendered or not